# match with typeof in fsharp

Tags: f#, if-statement, design-patterns, match

The first match works, but not the second one.
Is there any way to match without declaring variables, beside using a chain of if/elif ?

(Note that I use the value elem, while I match the variable t)

```
  let t = typeof<string>
  match propType with
  | t               ->  elem.GetValueAsString() :> obj
  | typeof<string>  ->  elem.GetValueAsString() :> obj
```

Comment: Were you trying to match depending the underlying type of an object or were you just puzzled about your result?

Comment: no I have the type, and the underlying type of my type variable will always be Type.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your first pattern actually doesn't match `typeof<string>`. It binds `propType` to a new value `t` shadowing the previous `t` which is equals to `typeof<string>`.

Since `typeof<string>` is not a literal, the second pattern doesn't work as well (although it is a redundant pattern in your example). You have to use `when` guard as follows:

```
  match propType with
  | t when t = typeof<string> -> elem.GetValueAsString() :> obj
  | t ->  elem.GetValueAsString() :> obj
```

Answer (score 9):

If you're trying to match against the type of a value, you can use the :? operator

Example :

```
let testMatch (toMatch:obj) = match toMatch with
                        | :? string as s -> s.Split([|';'|]).[0]
                        | :? int as i -> (i+1).ToString()
                        | _ -> String.Empty
```

Comment: in my case toMatch is the type itself. so only guards works afaik.

Comment: This was not the answer to this particular question, but it was to my question. :)